# If $f_{11} \geq 0$, $f_{22} \geq 0$, $f_{11}f_{22} \geq f_{12}^2$ then f is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $f_{11} \geq 0$, $f_{22} \geq 0$, $f_{11}f_{22} \geq f_{12}^2$ then f is convex.
Let $(x,y) , (x',y')$  and $t \in [0,1]$. We define $g(t)=f(t(x',y')+(1-t)(x,y))$, if $g(t)$ is convex then $f$ is convex but i don't understand that, could you give that reason?

Comment: The $g$ part just says that $f$ is convex on the line segment joining $(x,y), (x',y')$. It parameterises the line segment with $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

$t=t(1)+(1-t)(0)$. If $g$ is convex then this gives $g(t) \leq tg(1)+(1-t)g(0)$. This is exactly the definition of convexity of $f$ because $g(0)=f(x,y)$ and $g(1)=f(x',y')$.